# Google Maps API - custom overlay jumping to repeated map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a custom overlay that covers a large part of the world map (ideally the whole world - inside the overlay I want to use an SVG or canvas that would only uncover selected parts of the map). Here is an example that demonstrates my issue:

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      },
    }
  );

  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20, -100),
    new google.maps.LatLng(+20, 100)
  );

  class CustomOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
    bounds_
    div_

    constructor(bounds, image) {
      super();
      this.bounds_ = bounds;
      this.div_ = null;
    }

    onAdd() {
      this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
      this.div_.style.width = '100%'
      this.div_.style.height = '100%'
      this.div_.style.position = "absolute";
      this.div_.style.background = "red"

      const panes = this.getPanes();

      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(this.div_);
    }

    draw() {
      const overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      const sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
        this.bounds_.getSouthWest()
      );
      const ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
        this.bounds_.getNorthEast()
      );

      if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.left = sw.x + "px";
        this.div_.style.top = ne.y + "px";
        this.div_.style.width = ne.x - sw.x + "px";
        this.div_.style.height = sw.y - ne.y + "px";
      }
    }

    onRemove() {
      if (this.div_) {
        (this.div_.parentNode).removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
      }
    }
  }

  const overlay = new CustomOverlay(bounds);

  overlay.setMap(map);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rectangle Zoom</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is: whenever I zoom into an area in the eastern part of the red rectangle (Sri Lanka, Malaysia) the overlay disappears.

When I zoom out and pan the map I can see that the overlay is not disappearing - it's just moving to the next "repeated copy" of the map to the east.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here are some of my ideas, but I can't find a way to implement any of them:

- Disabling map repeating (only show one world map) - restricting the scrolling area doesn't fix the problem, I've tried
- Locking my overlay to the correct "copy" of the map or show it on every "copy"
- Using something different than a custom overlay (a polygon or rectangle won't work because I want to put an image or custom HTML element inside the map)

EDIT: I've just posted this issue on the Google Issue Tracker - [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/235362782)

Comment: This *looks* like a bug. I can't think of any way to prevent this behavior and couldn't find this behavior described anywhere. I would expect the overlay to not move, at least while it is visible within the viewport. I could not find an existing issue either so I would suggest you head to their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) and file a new bug. Don't expect them to fix this too soon though.

Comment: If you do open a new issue, please provide a link to this question in it, so they have a working code example, and once done, please edit your question to include a link to the issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you for the instructions. I've done what you said and added the issue link to the question.